# Only js file per page in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

In a Laravel setup using Laravel mix, the `mix.js(['resources/js/app.js','resources/js/new-offer.js'], 'public/js')` puts everything in one file, `app.js`.

What I am trying to achieve is to have multiple `.js` files each for one page. For example. I want to have index.js for my `index.blade.php` and `new-offer.js` for my `new-offer.blade.php` etc ...

The idea is that each page is server side rendered and each page represents a static page comming fromm the server and each one should has it's own set of js files that works in. How this should be done, is it recommended, what are other arhcitectures ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple concatenated `.js(...)` statements. In your case:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js','public/js').js('resources/js/new-offer.js' ,'public/js')
```

This will create`app.js` and `new-offer.js` files in your public js folder

Comment: So far this has been the only idea that came through my mind...